# I have created a contactform using mailfunction. But all the mails are going to spam.My code is given below

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I have created a contactform using mailfunction. But all the mails are going to spam.My code is given below

```
<?php 

//  MAIL SEND PHP

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "abc@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $email = $_POST['mail'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $subject = "Form submission";
    $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
    $message = $email . " " . $name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
    // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
    }

    // END MAIL SEND PHP
?>
```

Comment: Emails going to spam is nothing to do with the code you have implemented. They are going to spam because of the domain from which you are sending the emails.

Comment: Have you got SPF\DKIM set up for your email domain?  Email deliverability is probably unrelated to the code you use to send the email, and more likely related to what you are sending or where you are sending it from

Comment: This seems more a problem on your server's configuration. You should look for have a look at PTR & SPF records https://www.epinionated.net/stop-email-spam-spf-dkim/

Answer (score 0):

as i previously facing this issue , you can use phpmailer for this problem. with smtp details, hope fully that will working correctly.
checkout this link- [click here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)